# Handling intra-git-repository links when exporting Markdown to GitHub Pages

Tags: jekyll, github-pages

We have Markdown files accompanying our code that link to source files. This is convenient because the links work for offline access as well as on github.com.

When exporting to GitHub Pages, these relative links no longer work. If we're publishing the [master] branch to github.io, the links to source/file.h would need to be rewritten to [https://github.com/[user]/[repo]/blob/master/source/file.h](https://github.com/%5Buser%5D/%5Brepo%5D/blob/master/source/file.h).

(An advanced alternative: rewrite to some doxygen output for file.h instead? Would perhaps have to become .../source/file_8h_source.html or similar.)

Do I need to write a Jekyll plugin if we want this? Or is there some simpler way to accomplish it? (Something similar to https://github.com/benbalter/jekyll-relative-links perhaps.)

Comment: I've looked at various other stackoverflow questions on the topic of relative links in GitHub Pages, but these seem to be mostly about links to Markdown files (now handled under the hood in export) or trying to reference .css files, or something else not quite like what we need.